# how to increase character limit for visual basic alert boxes

Tags: vb6

I have the following code:

```
If Not strValidate ="" Then
    alert("The following information is required:" + vbLf + strValidate) 
    ValidateDocument = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

The variable "strValidate" contains a long number of characters, so when the alert box shows, it doesn't show the whole string, the remaining characters are cut off on the alert box.

Comment: A MsgBox or MessageBox will stretch to show all the text.

Comment: I would like to think it would but this string applied to the message box is like over 5000 characters, doesnt all, at the end it shows '....'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write your own Messagebox with a Scrollable Label/Textbox. There are already many custom messageboxes on the internet, so you can pick one and customize them.